# How To Make Favorite Button of Checkbox in Html

Tags: jquery, html, css

My Project Is Related E-Commerce Site And I Want To Add Favorite Button In Product Details Page.

Like We Use Toggle Switch Using Radio Button,
How To Make Favorite Button Using Checkbox???

Please Tell Me If You Have Any Other Suggestions Related To Favorite Product Concept..

Thanks In Advance........

Comment: What have u tried so far? :)

Comment: What css framework are you using if any? Bootstrap has examples of doing that using their css. www.getbootstrap.com

Comment: I Completed Totallay Database Structure & Designing Neglecting This Favorite Concept. In My Template Favorite Is A Botton But I Can't Convert It Into Checkbox Button. and I Am Use Bootstrap

Comment: Provide us with a concise and precise piece of code where we can see what u have tried to accomplish. We will help by fixing the code or at least give u suggestions for improvements. Try rpovide a demo on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I am aware that no JQuery has been specified in this question, I am providing this solution for other people as well who might be looking for the same thing:

```
<div>
  <span class="star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
</div>

<br/>

<div>
  <i class="heart fa fa-heart-o"></i>
</div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69ww31n3/)

Bootstrap Glyphicons and Font Awesome have been used for the icons

And JQuery has been used to handle the `class` toggling to change the icons.

CSS has only been used for the colors.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Ahs N.....It Will Be Tooo Much Helpful For Me......Again Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helps you then. Do mark it as answer if this answers your questions so that it can help others as well.

Comment: the question is `How To Make Favorite Button of Checkbox in Html` I dont see any checkbox used, Also how will the user save the values when marked as favorite ?

Comment: @Reddy The idea was to have a 'checkbox' like toggle. And since this has two states, either clicked or not clicked, checking for the class present is determine whether its clicked of not, which is pretty easy to do.

Comment: It is indeed, But I think this might not fit the Question title. But still gives a good idea on how to go about it.. Ill add my inputs as well.

Comment: @Reddy I do agree with you. But this is the easiest way I would have done it.

Comment: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/jquery-checkbox-buttons  and http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/checkboxradio-css-only might help with checkboxes too along with icons